# MustUnderstand attribute in WCF response causes error for Java/Axis client

Tags: wcf, soap, axis

We have developed a WCF4 service with usernameToken authentication that is being consumed by a Java/Axis client (that we have no control over).

I can see that the body of the request coming in looks like this...

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soapenv:Header>
    <wss:Security xmlns:wss="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <wss:UsernameToken>
        <wss:Username>username</wss:Username>
        <wss:Password>password</wss:Password>
      </wss:UsernameToken>
    </wss:Security>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    {snipped}
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and the response we are returning looks like this...

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <s:Header>
    <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
      <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
        <u:Created>2012-05-02T01:23:12.711Z</u:Created>
        <u:Expires>2012-05-02T01:28:12.711Z</u:Expires>
      </u:Timestamp>
    </o:Security>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    {snipped}
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

The problem is the s:mustUnderstand="1" attribute in the response. This is causing a "Must Understand check failed" error in the Java/Axis client.

Does anyone know how to configure WCF to remove this s:mustUnderstand attribute or at least set it to "0" instead of "1"?

Comment: does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551738/how-to-modify-a-wcf-message-headers-mustunderstand-using-clientinspector

Comment: What is your security configuration? Perhaps removing the timestamp from the configuration would solve the problem. Otherwise you will have to implement custom message encoder to modify the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution we came up with to overcome this interop problem was to change to a custom binding and specify the includeTimestamp="false" attribute. By doing this the timestamps (Created and Expired) were not added into the response and therefore the whole security header dissapeared - including the mustUnderstand attribute which was causing all the problems.

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="customBindingConfig">
        <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" includeTimestamp="false" />
         <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" />
         <httpTransport />
   </binding>
</customBinding>
```

So the response now simply looks like this...

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        {snipped}
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Did you have the timestamp indicated in the service.xml of the service?

Comment: @Brian,  I don't know. I left the company a few months ago so don't have access to the source code - sorry!