# SOAP Response change mustUnderstand to 0 for Action

Tags: web-services, wcf, soap, soap-client

The below code is an example from microsoft here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.messageheaderattribute?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0

```
[MessageContract]
 public class HelloResponseMessage
 {
   private string localResponse = String.Empty;
   private string extra = String.Empty;

   [MessageBodyMember(
     Name = "ResponseToGreeting",
     Namespace = "http://www.examples.com")]
   public string Response
   {
     get { return localResponse; }
     set { localResponse = value; }
   }

   [MessageHeader(
     Name = "OutOfBandData",
     Namespace = "http://www.examples.com",
     MustUnderstand=true
   )]
   public string ExtraValues
   {
     get { return extra; }
     set { this.extra = value; }
  }

  /*
   The following is the response message, edited for clarity.

   <s:Envelope>
     <s:Header>
       <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://HelloResponseMessage/Action</a:Action>
       <h:OutOfBandData s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:h="http://www.examples.com">Served by object 13804354.</h:OutOfBandData>
     </s:Header>
     <s:Body>
       <HelloResponseMessage xmlns="Microsoft.WCF.Documentation">
         <ResponseToGreeting xmlns="http://www.examples.com">Service received: Hello.</ResponseToGreeting>
       </HelloResponseMessage>
     </s:Body>
   </s:Envelope>
   */
}
```

However, what I want to do is change the mustUnderstand field to 0 or false on the Action or any other field in the Header i.e.

> ```
>  <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://HelloResponseMessage/Action</a:Action>
> ```

to

> ```
> <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="0">http://HelloResponseMessage/Action</a:Action>
> ```

The reason I want to do this is because I have a WCF Web Service that sends the following response back:

```
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
    xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
    xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">...</a:Action>
        <a:RelatesTo>M90319394</a:RelatesTo>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1"
            xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="_0">
                <u:Created>2022-11-17T02:35:29.599Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2022-11-17T02:40:29.599Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        ...
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

It works fine in SoapUI but the for user who is sending the Soap Request via their system, they are getting the following error with that SOAP Response:

> Error sending/receiving.  More info: org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Must Understand check failed for header http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd : Security

Can anyone please help with this?

Comment: What are the specific error messages?

Comment: @Jiayao I have updated the ticket with more info showing the SOAP Response my WCF Service is sending and the error the user is getting on their end.

Comment: You may take a look at [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3551738/how-to-modify-a-wcf-message-headers-mustunderstand-using-clientinspector).